# How to provide an optional fill parameter in ggplot2 graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2

The desired behavior is to produce a graph with fill color based on a variable that may be NULL (meaning no fill). This is possible for each situation independently, but not together.

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mpg, aes(class, hwy))
fill_var <- "class"
p + geom_boxplot(aes(fill = if(is.null(fill_var)){fill_var}else{!!sym(fill_var)}))
```

[image: fill with variably named column]

```
fill_var <- NULL
p + geom_boxplot(aes(fill = if(is.null(fill_var)){fill_var}else{!!sym(fill_var)}))
```

> Error: Only strings can be converted to symbols

This is surprising to me because the `else` condition is not supposed to be evaluated and therefore the non-string `NULL` should not be converted to a symbol. Setting `fill=NULL` works perfectly fine:

```
p + geom_boxplot(aes(fill = NULL))
```

[image: fill with staticly defined NULL]

How do I achieve this conditional fill?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what's going on with `sym()`, but this seems like a good use case for the `.data` pronoun.  Replace `!!sym(fill_var)` with `.data[[fill_var]]`.

However, I now see that going this route leaves much to be desired on the legend name.  I agree with whichever answer said to put the process into a function and added layers depending on the `if()` statement. That is generally how I'd tackle this.

```
fill_var <- "class"
p + geom_boxplot(aes(fill = if(is.null(fill_var)) {fill_var} else {.data[[fill_var]]}))
```

[image]

```
fill_var <- NULL
p + geom_boxplot(aes(fill = if(is.null(fill_var)) {fill_var} else {.data[[fill_var]]}))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-03-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You can try `aes_string`. Than you do not need an if-condition because `NULL` and a string of a colname  will automatically treated equaly.

```
fill_var <- NULL
p <- ggplot(mpg, aes(class, hwy))
p + geom_boxplot(aes_string(fill = fill_var))
```

[image]

```
fill_var <-"class"
p <- ggplot(mpg, aes(class, hwy))
p + geom_boxplot(aes_string(fill = fill_var))
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! But looking at the original post, I am still wondering why OPs code doesn't work. The behaviour seems strange.

Comment: aes_string is soft-deprecated (https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_.html). I am following the instruction to "Please use tidy evaluation idioms instead".

Answer (score 0):

Untested code

```
fill_var <- NULL
p <- ggplot(mpg, aes(class, hwy))
if (is.null(fill_var)) {
  p <- p + geom_boxplot()
} else {
  p + geom_boxplot(aes(fill = fill_var))
}
p
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for. Mind it works for all columns of `mpg` dataset

```
make_plot <- function(fill_var = NULL){
  p <- ggplot(mpg, aes(class, hwy))

  if(is.null(fill_var)){
    p + 
      geom_boxplot()
    
  }else{

    ggplot(mpg, aes(class, hwy, fill = !!sym(fill_var)))+
      geom_boxplot()
  }
  
}
```